# Rspec Error: undefined local variable or method `cookies' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups...etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, rspec, capybara

I, like everybody else, have an app that behaves differently depending on whether a user is logged in or not. I am having troubles logging a user in through my SessionsHelper since Rspec seems to have no definition of the 'cookies' variable.
Here's my SessionsHelper module with relevant code:

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in user
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

end
```

and here is the code within my spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

include SessionsHelper

describe "Topic#create features" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  before do
    visit topics_path
  end
end

context "when user is logged in" do
  before do
    sign_in user
    visit current_path
  end


 // Some tests written here

end
```

The following is the error I receive:

undefined local variable or method `cookies' for #

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The cookies hash is only available in RSpec's controller tests. You can tell your specs to pretend that they're controller specs by adding type: :request to your context, like so:

```
describe 'something that requires cookies', type: :request do
it { expect(cookies[:remember_token]).to be_nil } // now the variable is defined as nil.
end
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem remains since I'm trying to perform a feature test. By making it of type: :request I lose access to feature test functions like "visit example_path". I can easily test that my sign in function works in a controller test, the problem is I cant do both. I cant sign in within my feature test, and therefore I cant test a feature like filling in a form that is only available to signed in users.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst Zoinks10 answer is correct, it unfortunately didn't meet my needs (unless I did something wrong).

A nice work around I found was to create a support directory in the spec folder (Any files in this folder will be loaded automatically in your specs so it's nice to name it "support").

I then wrote the actual function for navigating the page and logging on via capy_bara:

```
// spec/support/utilities.rb

include ApplicationHelper    

def sign_in(user)
  visit signin_path
  fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
  fill_in "Password", with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in"
end
```

Seems obvious now that I think about it - Hope it helps anybody who reaches a road block due to this issue